# How can I disable blinking cursor when editing text in Mail.app or Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, mail.app

In macOS Monterey when I use native Mail.app to compose a mail or in Safari typing here to ask the question, the cursor blinks.

Is it possible to prevent blinking cursor and if possible to replace it to filled box like:
[image]

In order to disable blinking, I have tried: `defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriod -float 4000000000`, which did not helped.

Related: https://superuser.com/questions/466660/how-to-disable-blinking-caret-when-editing-text-in-os-x

Comment: Ah I have tried both of your recommendations but it did not had any effect. Does it require reboot?

Comment: I've just proposed adding the macOS tag to help others find the question more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following commands should set the on blink to 10 seconds and the off blink to ten seconds (the default is 1).

```
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOn -float 1000000
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOff -float 1000000
```

Those numbers can be changed to what you want but keep in mind that they are interpreted in milliseconds.

Comment: I have run them but still it blinks :-( what could be the reason for this?

Comment: @alper Oops, it was supposed to be 1,000,000. This will set the on and off blink to 10s but you can of course set them to more if you want. Just remember the number you put there is in milliseconds.

Comment: Does it work on your end? I have tried your solutions also @Allan 's at the comment but it does not have any affect :-( What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @alper Yes, that works for me. It didn't work at first with 0 and even after changing to 1000000. But I rebooted and it now works with 1000000 (and other numbers). - Try rebooting and trying again both methods (Allan's and mine)

Comment: For example while I am typing this comment it blinks or in Mail.app :-( // But now it does not blink at Pages.app

Comment: @alper Yeah, this will work depending on how the app was built. It will work for certain apps but not others. I've tried Mail and it doesn't work either. It will also depend on third-party apps.

Comment: Ah I think there is no work around for Mail.app or Thunderbird :-( Thanks anyway

Comment: @alper You're welcome. I'll try to find something that will work for those at least (although better system-wide). I'll contact you if I do.